# C++: Type Erasure Virtual Template Workaround

Tags: c++, templates, type-erasure

I am using the type erasure design pattern to expose a template-independent interface for one of my template classes. However, I have run into the problem that one of the methods that I wish to expose, which fuses two templated instances into a third instance with a different template constant parameter argument, seems to require template virtual methods, which are illegal.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

template<size_t N>
class bar
{
    template<size_t M>
    bar<M+N> fuse(const bar<M>& rhs) { return bar<M+N>(); }
};

class bar_any_N 
{
private:
    class abstract_base
    {
        virtual bar_any_N fuse(const abstract_base* rhs) = 0;

        template<size_t M>
        virtual bar_any_N fuse_accept(const bar<M>& lhs) = 0;
    };

    template<size_t N>
    class wrapper : public abstract_base
    {
    private:
        bar<N> m_bar;
    public:
        wrapper(const bar<N>& the_bar) : m_bar(the_bar) { }

        bar_any_N fuse(const abstract_base* rhs) { return rhs->fuse_accept(*this); }

        template<size_t M>
        bar_any_N fuse_accept(const bar<M>& lhs) { return lhs.m_bar.fuse(this->m_bar) }
    };

    abstract_base* m_ptr;
public:
    template<size_t N> 
    bar_any_N(const bar<N>& the_bar) { m_ptr = new wrapper<N>(the_bar); }

};

int main()
{
    bar<1> b1;
    bar<2> b2;
    bar_any_N b1_erased(b1);
    bar_any_N b2_erased(b2);

    bar_any_N b3 = b1_erased.fuse(b2_erased);

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have another way to implement this that would not require a virtual template member?

EDIT: The purpose of this 'template independent interface' is to pass vectors of bar instances with different template parameters to functions:

```
std::vector< bar_any_N > vec; 
vec.push_back(bar<2>()); 
vec.push_back(bar<5>()); 
foo_func(vec);
```

EDIT:

Here is a simpler working example with a printing method instead of the above fuse method that shows how I would LIKE this to work:

http://codepad.org/8UbJguCR

Comment: Is `fuse_accept` the problem? If so why don't you implement it non-virtually in `abstract_base`?

Comment: abstract_base does not (and cannot, as it would force it to be templated) have the member m_bar, and so the method needs to be virtual to have access to this member.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'template-independent interface'

Comment: @JohanLundberg please see my edit above

Comment: Is there an upper limit on `M`?  If not, problem.  At type erasure time, all methods that can be instantiated must be.  With no upper limit on `M`, this is impossible (well, max `size_t` is an upper limit, so merely impractical).  Why must `N` be a compile time parameter?

Comment: There is no upper limit on M, so perhaps it is impossible :( N is a compile time parameter for debugging convenience; in real life, bar<N> is a tensor of order N, and its methods take lists of blocks strictly of length N.

Comment: @SamManzer Wait, what?  `N` is a compile time constant just for debugging convenience?

Comment: @Yakk largely yes; it also makes the implementation of the class somewhat cleaner (all member arrays are size N etc...), but the main benefit is the compiler catches it if I ask the offset of a block in a 3d tensor (needs 3 indices) and only pass 2 indices. If it wasn't a constant, would need to use std::vector or something and not have that safety.

Comment: I think I kind of understand what you want to do, but I think the question would be more clear if you actually presented code that compiled correctly, but doesn't do what you want. What you have is code that doesn't compile and you are asking us to understand what it is you actually want.

Comment: @jxh I've added a link at the bottom of the post that shows how this type erasure code works for a simple printing method. I encounter this perceived need for virtual templates when I want to use a method that has two templated arguments such the fuse method above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do inside out type erasure.

```
struct bar_raw
{
  std::size_t N;
  explicit bar_raw( std::size_t n ):N(n) {}
  bar_raw fuse( const bar_raw& rhs ) { return bar_raw(N+rhs.N); }
};
template<size_t N>
struct bar: bar_raw
{
  bar():bar_raw(N) {}
  template<size_t M>
  bar<M+N> fuse(const bar<M>& rhs) { return bar<M+N>(); }
};
```

Keep all state in `bar_raw`.  Have a pretty interface that helps writing code in `bar<N>`, like n-ary indexes.

When passed a `bar<N>` to type erase, you ignore the `bar<N>` component and type erase the `bar_raw`, which is pretty trivial.

You could call `bar_raw` your `bar_any` if you wanted, or you could leave `bar_raw` as an implementation detail, and wrap it in a `bar_any` that is all pretty.

Comment: Just adding my two cents: the only 'problem' with this is that the type system for the whole situation gets a bit confusing and screwy; expect to perform a lot of type casting or roll-your-own-RTTI if you want to consistently get the templated subclass. That's what you get for trying to subvert the limitation of no-virtual-templates, though. Or for trying to turn infinity into a finite number. It's basically the same problem for the compiler worded either way. :-P

Comment: @Atash which is why I think that `bar_raw` should be a private detail.  The type-erased case cannot expose the templated subclass, as it is type-erased.  When working with `bar<N>`, its pretty interface does a pile of type magic to produce the resulting type, and it takes as arguments only `bar<M>` types, so it can do the math on those types without any hackery.  The internal `bar_raw` ends up having to duplicate much of this work, but it manages the runtime state (which you prove and assert aligns with the compile time state).  The erasure object only cares about runtime state.

Comment: I think that I will probably do something like this; however, does anyone know if there is an alternative using RTTI/dynamic_cast to typecast the abstract_base pointers to the appropriate wrapper<N> type?

Comment: @SamManzer If you want to support the RTTI bit, you have to add in some runtime information. This means an extra field in your `bar` class held by each object (like above), or parsing the result of `typeid()` (blech), etc. The best you can do (afaik) for the casting is a jump-table/`switch`-statement on all useful values of `N` for `bar<N>` for every bit of code that you want to have using the appropriate `wrapper<N>` type as opposed to some base class. You can trampoline this using some template metaprogramming, but it'll be a pain. It might make more sense to just use straight polymorphism.